# convert generalization to mysql scheme

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, uml

i drew this layout scheme, but now i need to convert for a "`mysql` layout". So the `generalization` must use two `junction tables`, correct? (one for student and other for worker)

An about the `multiplicity`, users can be workers or students, but one user only can be one worker and one worker only can be an user? this does not make much sense...?

basically, how i can convert this `generalization` for something that can be executable for `mysql` code.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to define three tables: users, workers, and students. The workers and students tables each has a user_id field that is a foreign key tied to the same field in the users table.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways ORM's do it

First way is give them each a separate table and join the tables. (3tables)

Second way only works if your users class is abstract, then then you take 2 tables for your sub-classes.

And the last and my favorite way.
you stuff everything in one table, and introduce a discriminator column.
basically make a table containing all the fields of users, student and worker.
add an extra column for the type and fill em up accordingly.
You can select all students / workers easily using the discriminator column, and you don 't have to spam joins. The downside is it takes up extra space.

Comment: @last suggestion -but the content in the table users is for each user, specific content, and the data in the worker table can be shared for different users- two designers, bob and john can earn the same salary. this is why I created three tables in the schema.

Comment: What if bob got a raise and john didn't? In this case the problem shouldn't be solved with a generalization but with a relation like Ted Hopp suggested